# Ola’s Journeys: Adventures in _____

Tags: rhyme, steganography, geography

Ah, hello.
My friend Ola, well, she’s from UNESCO.
‘Ḅout her, there’s one thing you should know:

Her favorite coloŗ, is simply yellow.
She also likes lists. There’s not much that works that rhymes with lists…

She’s taken a vacation,
To æ large, un-new nation,
and went
and spent
all the time
she was there in the same old place, it’s such a shame.

Well, she sent me a letter

Hoping I’d get better

At her pużzles.
Here’s one:
My work computer has a website on įt. It’s important, becuase it has my favorite things!
Łists!

Such fun!

Anyways, I’ve hidden things, easy to spot, that tell you a nation.
Go down, all the way, to said station.
My favorite color, my favorite country! Ah, landscapes between the mountain and the sea!
Well, I guess, that’s enough from me.

**Where did Ola go on vacation? AKA, what CITY/MONUMENTS did she visit?**

Comment: My bad for not properly explaining it. I wish I could upvote y’all. RIP good answers.

Comment: I should have known it wouldn't be that easy...

Comment: It’s not like I’m salty or anything, it isn’t that easy.

Comment: It, sadly, @Dopplegamer, does involve use of _______. No! Thou shalt not drop hints obsessive compulsively!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Rio de Janeiro, Brazil!

Because

> certain characters in the text have weird marks on them. They spell out ḄŗæżįŁ.

The website mentioned

> is the UNESCO website which is also mentioned. It features lists, Ola's favorite thing. On the World Heritage List, if you scroll down to Brazil, it has a lot of yellow diamonds in the list. Ola's favorite color. One of them is "Rio de Janeiro: Carioca Landscapes between the Mountain and the Sea" which matches the description in the puzzle.

Comment: Darn! I was 18 seconds too late!

Comment: Dang! Too late again, even on the real answer!

Comment: You sniped Dopple. Same regards from Ola, J'cl am mbtk. H'tw cv rtvyjeg z aafclmo mfv tgqd uzmd. Ppivhdpp.

Comment: @Dopplegamer Haha I thought you had beaten me to the country. Either way nice job all around.

Comment: @someoneinexistence haha looking forward to it bzzzz. Did I spell that right?

Answer (score 3):

> Rio de Janeiro!

We know this because

> There are unicode letters throughout the puzzle that spell out ḄŗæżįŁ when we put them together, or Brazil in their non-unicode form. Therefore, that is most likely the country where she went.

Now we also know three things:

> - She likes the color yellow.

> - She is in the "landscapes between the mountain and the sea."

and

> - There is a list on her work computer.

The final solution:

> If we go to the Brazilian Convention on the UNESCO (Ola's job) website, then go to the "Properties inscribed on the World Heritage List", one of the **yellow** markers on the map is "Rio de Janeiro: Carioca *Landscapes between the Mountain and the Sea*" (emphasis added).

(Sorry, about all the blockquotes. It's difficult to chain together bullet points within them.)

Comment: Oops! I was trying to ask **Which PLACE is she in**, but didn’t get to that. I’m sorry I can’t reward you, but you’re there.

Comment: That’s right! Thanks for answering! In regards to Ola, J'cl am mbtk. H'tw cv rtvyjeg z aafclmo mfv tgqd uzmd. Ppivhdpp.